# How to fix backtrace line number error in C++

Tags: c++, macos, debug-symbols, backtrace

I got a problem while wants to trace some information on program catches exceptions.

I used the function below:

```
extern "C" void log_backtrace()
{   
    // Dump the callstack
    int callstack[128];
    int  frames = backtrace((void**) callstack, 128);
    char** strs = backtrace_symbols((void**) callstack, frames);

    for (int i = 1; i < frames; ++i)
    {
        char functionSymbol[64*1024];
        char moduleName    [64*1024];
        int  offset        = 0;
        sscanf(strs[i], "%*d %s %*s %s %*s %d", &moduleName, &functionSymbol, &offset);
        int addr = callstack[i];
        int   validCppName;
        char* functionName = abi::__cxa_demangle(functionSymbol, NULL, 0,
                                             &validCppName);
        if (validCppName == 0)
            printf(   "\t%8.8x — %s + %d\t\t(%s)\n", addr, functionName, offset, moduleName);
        else
            printf(   "\t%8.8x — %s + %d\t\t(%s)\n", addr, functionSymbol, offset, moduleName);
        if (functionName)
            free(functionName);
    }
    free(strs);
}
```

And the output is like this:

```
20:48:44 [ERROR]tcp_client::connect() failed. error:Connection refused
00000001 — latte::Log::out_error(std::string const&) + 151      (valhalla)
001a6637 — latte::tcp_client::connect(boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> const&) + 307       (valhalla)
00000001 — valhalla::hall::start() + 388        (valhalla)
00204803 — main + 388       (valhalla)
00000001 — start + 52       (valhalla)
00143ae4 — 0x0 + 1      (???)
```

All the information (the namespaces, class names and the method names) are good. But the only problem is the line numbers are wrong.

How can I fix the line numbers in the backtrace?

Comment: I used GCC / LLVM-GCC in Mac OSX 10.7, Thanks :)

Comment: Your `callstack` variable is the wrong type so this won't work on 64-bit systems.  Use `void*` instead of `int`.

Comment: I'm on osx 10.13.6, compiling with g++. When I compile with `-g` I get debugging symbols and the stacktrace in the core dump in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` displays line numbers now

Answer (score 12):

They're not line numbers, but offsets from the start of the function. There's a tool called `addr2line` which is shipped with binutils that can convert addresses into line numbers given debug symbols. You could either call this from within your program (`pipe()`+`fork()`+`exec()`), or look at the library it uses to do this.

On my Linux system addr2line uses [libbfd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library) internally for this. It's not terribly well documented though from what I've seen, but it's reasonably easy to see by example from the addr2line source.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and hunted around for a solution, however I didn't find anything. You have tagged OSX in your post, so I am assuming that is the platform you want this to work on? Well OSX doesn't have addr2line, at least it isn't in OSX version 10.8/10.9. I put together the code below (using snippets from various sources), and it generates backtraces that look like this (it includes the top two frames which are the exception handler, you can skip this if you wish):

```
Caught SIGBUG: Bus error (bad memory access)
 0 MyGame                                     0x342878   ExceptionHandler::PrintStackTrace() (in MyGame) (MacOSXEngine.cpp:89)
 1 MyGame                                     0x342c4e   ExceptionHandler::Handler(int, __siginfo*, void*) (in MyGame) (MacOSXEngine.cpp:232)
 2 libsystem_platform.dylib                 0x92beedeb   0x92beedeb
 3 ???                                      0xffffffff   0 + 4294967295
 4 MyGame                                     0x48ae93   GlfwGraphicsSystem::Initialise(PiEngine::EmulationMode::T, PiGraphics::Orientation::T) (in MyGame) (GlfwGraphicsSystem.cpp:29)
 5 MyGame                                     0x343f1f   MacOSXEngine::Initialise() (in MyGame) (MacOSXEngine.cpp:581)
 6 MyGame                                     0x342f8f   main (in MyGame) (MacOSXEngine.cpp:304)
 7 MyGame                                       0x3445   start (in MyGame) + 53
```

It only produces function + file + line number for frames within the executing module. The code is will only work on OSX but could be adapted to work on other platforms. There are going to be corner cases not covered, but hopefully this is a good starting point. The code is:

```
namespace ExceptionHandler
{
    char m_ExeFilename[ PATH_MAX ];

    // Execute cmd store stdout into buf (up to bufSize).
    int Execute( const char * cmd, char * buf, size_t bufSize )
    {
        char filename[ 512 ];
        sprintf( filename, "%d.tmp", rand( ) );

        if ( FILE * file = fopen( filename, "w" ) )
        {
            if ( FILE * ptr = popen( cmd, "r" ) ) 
            {
                while ( fgets( buf, bufSize, ptr ) != NULL )
                {
                    fprintf( file, "%s", buf );
                }
                pclose( ptr );
            }
            fclose( file );

            unlink( filename );

            return 0;   
        }

        return -1;
    }

    // Resolve symbol name and source location given the path to the executable and an address
    int Addr2Line(char const * const program_name, void const * const addr, char * buff, size_t buffSize )
    {
        char addr2line_cmd[512] = {0};
        sprintf( addr2line_cmd, "atos -d -o %.256s %p", program_name, addr ); 
        return Execute( addr2line_cmd, buff, buffSize );
    }

    // Check if file exists.
    bool FileExists( const char * filename )
    {
        if ( FILE * fh = fopen( filename, "r" ) )
        {
            fclose( fh );
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Print stack trace.
    void PrintStackTrace( )
    {
        int trace_size = 0;
        char ** messages = ( char ** )NULL;

        static const size_t kMaxStackFrames = 64;
        static void * stack_traces[ kMaxStackFrames ];
        trace_size = backtrace( stack_traces, kMaxStackFrames );
        messages = backtrace_symbols( stack_traces, trace_size );

        for ( int i = 0; i < trace_size; ++i )
        {
            int stackLevel;
            char filename[ 512 ];
            uintptr_t address;
            char symbol[ 512 ];
            uintptr_t symbolOffset;
            uintptr_t functionOffset;
            bool symbolOffsetValid = false;
            bool somethingValid = true;

            if ( sscanf( messages[ i ], "%d%*[ \t]%s%*[ \t]%" SCNxPTR "%*[ \t]%" SCNxPTR "%*[ \t]+%*[ \t]%" SCNuPTR, &stackLevel, filename, &address, &symbolOffset, &functionOffset ) == 5 )
            {
                symbolOffsetValid = true;
            }
            else if ( sscanf( messages[ i ], "%d%*[ \t]%s%*[ \t]%" SCNxPTR "%*[ \t]%s%*[ \t]+%*[ \t]%" SCNuPTR, &stackLevel, filename, &address, symbol, &functionOffset ) == 5 )
            {
            }
            else
            {
                somethingValid = false;
            }

            const size_t BUFF_SIZE = 4096;
            char buff[ BUFF_SIZE ] = { '\0' };

            if ( somethingValid )
            {
                if ( symbolOffsetValid && symbolOffset == 0 )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "%3d %-32s   %#16" PRIxPTR "   %#" PRIxPTR " + %" PRIuPTR "\n", stackLevel, filename, address, symbolOffset, functionOffset );
                }
                else if ( FileExists( m_ExeFilename ) && Addr2Line( m_ExeFilename, stack_traces[ i ], buff, BUFF_SIZE) == 0 )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "%3d %-32s   %#16" PRIxPTR "   %s", stackLevel, filename, address, buff );
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "%3d %-32s   %#16" PRIxPTR "   %#" PRIxPTR " + %" PRIuPTR "\n", stackLevel, filename, address, symbolOffset, functionOffset );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", messages[ i ] );
            }
        }
        if (messages) 
        { 
            free( messages ); 
        } 
    }

    void Handler( int sig, siginfo_t * siginfo, void * context )
    {
        switch(sig)
        {
            case SIGSEGV:
                fputs("Caught SIGSEGV: Segmentation Fault\n", stderr);
                break;

            case SIGBUS:
                fputs("Caught SIGBUG: Bus error (bad memory access)\n", stderr);
                break;

            case SIGINT:
                fputs("Caught SIGINT: Interactive attention signal, (usually ctrl+c)\n", stderr);
                break;

            case SIGFPE:
                switch(siginfo->si_code)
                {
                    case FPE_INTDIV:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (integer divide by zero)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case FPE_INTOVF:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (integer overflow)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case FPE_FLTDIV:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (floating-point divide by zero)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case FPE_FLTOVF:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (floating-point overflow)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case FPE_FLTUND:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (floating-point underflow)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case FPE_FLTRES:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (floating-point inexact result)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case FPE_FLTINV:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (floating-point invalid operation)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case FPE_FLTSUB:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: (subscript out of range)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    default:
                        fputs("Caught SIGFPE: Arithmetic Exception\n", stderr);
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case SIGILL:
                switch(siginfo->si_code)
                {
                    case ILL_ILLOPC:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (illegal opcode)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case ILL_ILLOPN:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (illegal operand)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case ILL_ILLADR:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (illegal addressing mode)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case ILL_ILLTRP:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (illegal trap)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case ILL_PRVOPC:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (privileged opcode)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case ILL_PRVREG:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (privileged register)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case ILL_COPROC:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (coprocessor error)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    case ILL_BADSTK:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: (internal stack error)\n", stderr);
                        break;
                    default:
                        fputs("Caught SIGILL: Illegal Instruction\n", stderr);
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case SIGTERM:
                fputs("Caught SIGTERM: a termination request was sent to the program\n", stderr);
                break;
            case SIGABRT:
                fputs("Caught SIGABRT: usually caused by an abort() or assert()\n", stderr);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        PrintStackTrace( );
        fflush( stderr );
        fflush( stdout );

        _exit( 1 );
    }

    bool Initialise( const char * argv )
    {
        char path[ PATH_MAX ];
        uint32_t size = sizeof( path );
        if ( _NSGetExecutablePath( path, &size ) == 0 )
        {
            if ( ! realpath( path, m_ExeFilename ) )
            {
                strcpy( m_ExeFilename, path );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy( m_ExeFilename, argv ? argv : "" );
        }

        struct sigaction sig_action = {};
        sig_action.sa_sigaction = Handler;
        sigemptyset(&sig_action.sa_mask);
        sig_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

        int toCatch[ ] = {
            SIGSEGV,
            SIGBUS,
            SIGFPE,
            SIGINT,
            SIGILL,
            SIGTERM,
            SIGABRT
        };

        bool okay = true;
        for ( size_t toCatchIx = 0; toCatchIx < PiArraySize( toCatch ); ++toCatchIx )
        {
            okay &= sigaction( toCatch[ toCatchIx ], &sig_action, NULL ) == 0;
        }

        return okay;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    argc = argc;
    argv = argv;

    ExceptionHandler::Initialise( argc > 0 ? argv[ 0 ] : NULL );

    // Do something

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize the original question is over a decade old - but I had the same question and just found the answer.  I'm on a Mac using cmake to generate makefile for AppleClang.

If you're using cmake to build your executable - you need to pass in the "-g" compiler option - like this:

add_compile_options(-g)

Then you need to run your executable using lldb like this:

lldb

then once in the lldb command line - you need to use the command "run", then you need to issue the backtrace command "bt".  Then you'll finally get line numbers for your crash.